# concatenation of string and numbers through variabes. throwing this " TypeError: must be str, not int"

Tags: python, typeerror

```
character_name = "sonie agarwal"
character_age = 21
print ("my Name is "+ character_name)
print ("my Age is " + character_age)
```

i am trying to run the above code in the pycharm but output is getting this output

> my Name is sonie agarwal
>
> File "C:/Users/deepu/PycharmProjects/trainingWithGirafee/app.py", line 5, in
>
> print ("my Age is " + character_age)
> TypeError: must be str, not int

Comment: Python is a [strongly typed language](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Why%20is%20Python%20a%20dynamic%20language%20and%20also%20a%20strongly%20typed%20language), so you have to sum strings with strings and ints with ints. In your case, you probably want `'my age is' + str(age)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
print("my Age is %d" % character_age)
print("my Name is %s" % character_name)
```

This is called `string formatting` and will allow you to inject types into strings without explicitly converting them. `%d` is interpreted as `float` or `double`, `%s` for `string` etc...

Explicit string concatenation forces you to manually convert your types, which can impair readability, but can be viewed as a stylistic preference on smaller scripts. On applications where speed is a must, string concatenation is generally slower than string formatting

Answer (score 0):

You can use either of these two solutions

```
character_name = "sonie agarwal"
character_age = 21
print ("my Name is %s" %character_name)
print ("my Age is %d"  %character_age)

character_name = "sonie agarwal"
character_age = 21
print ("my Name is "+ str(character_name))
print ("my Age is " + str(character_age))
```